# Shape changing when slicing numpy arrayx

Tags: arrays, numpy, reshape

I take the following array as example:

`lights = np.array([ [1,0,1], [0,1,1], [0,0,1], [1,1,1] ])`

`lights[0]`   returns a shape : `(3,)`

`lights[0:1]` returns a shape : `(1, 3)`

I do not understand what is numpy's logic in this case.
Given that the slice is exclusive, [0:1] is similar to [0].
So, why does it impact the shape of the array?

Comment: What happens if `lights`  is a list instead of an array?

Comment: @hpaulj I don't see what you are suggesting here. If it is a list, it has no shape and `lights[0:1]` wouldn't work either. Can you elaborate on what you are trying to say?

Comment: Indexing a list with a scalar removes a level of nesting.  Indexing with a slice preserves the nesting level.  Array and list behavior is consistent.

Comment: @hpaulj well this is interesting. I read your answer and tried the list slicing on a different computer as when I wrote my first comment. You are right, it is the same. For some strange reason, I got an error on the other computer. I have to check what's going on there tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing

> An integer, i, returns the same values as i:i+1 except the dimensionality of the returned object is reduced by 1. In particular, a selection tuple with the p-th element an integer (and all other entries :) returns the corresponding sub-array with dimension N - 1. If N = 1 then the returned object is an array scalar. These objects are explained in Scalars.

This `numpy` indexing with scalars versus slices is consistent with Python's list indexing:

```
In [119]: alist = [ [1,0,1], [0,1,1], [0,0,1], [1,1,1] ]                                               
In [120]: alist[0]                                                                                     
Out[120]: [1, 0, 1]     # one element of alist
In [121]: alist[0:1]                                                                                   
Out[121]: [[1, 0, 1]]    # a list with one element
In [122]: alist[0][1]    # nested selection of a number                                                     
Out[122]: 0
```

the array equilvalents, with matching use of []:

```
In [123]: arr = np.array(alist)                                                                        
In [124]: arr                                                                                          
Out[124]: 
array([[1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]])
In [125]: arr[0]                                                                                       
Out[125]: array([1, 0, 1])
In [126]: arr[0:1]                                                                                     
Out[126]: array([[1, 0, 1]])
In [127]: arr[0,1]                                                                                     
Out[127]: 0
```

`numpy` can also index with tuples, lists and arrays.

Answer (score 0):

`lights` is a 2d array of shape `(4,3)`.

In the case of `lights[0]`, you want the first element of that array, which is a 1d array of size 3 itself. Hence you get the shape `(3,)`.

Now with `lights[0:1]` you are not doing the same. You slice out a subarray. Even though this subarray contains only one element in one dimension, it is still a 2-dimensional array.

Ask yourself: What would happen, if you do `lights[0:2]`? You would expect a 2d array with the shape `(2,3)`, right? So even though the subarray returned by `lights[0:1]` might be identical to a 1d array, NumPy can't just drop that dimension for you.

If you type something like `lights[0:N]`, where N is a variable and NumPy drops 1 dimension automatically if `N=1` you would have to treat this special case separately every time. A simple example, you want to get a slice and set the second element of it:

```py
N = 2
t = lights[0:N]
t[0, 1] = 42
```

You can set N to 1 and it still works. Now change it to `t = lights[0]` and your program crashes in the next line since your array has only 1 dimension. So in case NumPy would drop the extra dimension for `lights[0:1]`, you would have to write extra code for this special case every time.